# Fitting polynomial model to data in R

Tags: r, curve-fitting, data-analysis, polynomial-math

I've read the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/382186/fitting-polynomials-to-data) and they are quite helpful, but I need help.

I have an example data set in R as follows:

```
x <- c(32,64,96,118,126,144,152.5,158)  
y <- c(99.5,104.8,108.5,100,86,64,35.3,15)
```

I want to fit a model to these data so that `y = f(x)`. I want it to be a 3rd order polynomial model.

How can I do that in R?

Additionally, can R help me to find the best fitting model?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

To get a third order polynomial in x (x^3), you can do

```
lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3))
```

or

```
lm(y ~ poly(x, 3, raw=TRUE))
```

You could fit a 10th order polynomial and get a near-perfect fit, but should you?

EDIT:
poly(x, 3) is probably a better choice (see @hadley below).

Comment: is spot on in asking "should you". The sample data only has 8 points. Degrees of freedom are pretty low here. The real life data may have a lot more, of course.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What about getting R to find the best fitting model? Are there any functions for this?

Comment: It depends on your definition of "best model". The model that gives you the greatest R^2 (which a 10th order polynomial would) is not necessarily the "best" model. The terms in your model need to be reasonably chosen. You can get a near-perfect fit with a lot of parameters but the model will have no predictive power and will be useless for anything other than drawing a best fit line through the points.

Comment: Why are you using `raw = T`?  It's better to use uncorrelated variables.

Comment: I did it to get the same results as `lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3))`. Perhaps not optimal, just giving two means to the same end.

Comment: What if there are multiple independent variables? Can we do something like `lm(y ~ x1 + I(x1^2) + I(x2*x1) + I(x2^2))`

Answer (score 51):

Which model is the "best fitting model" depends on what you mean by "best".  R has tools to help, but you need to provide the definition for "best" to choose between them.  Consider the following example data and code:

```
x <- 1:10
y <- x + c(-0.5,0.5)

plot(x,y, xlim=c(0,11), ylim=c(-1,12))

fit1 <- lm( y~offset(x) -1 )
fit2 <- lm( y~x )
fit3 <- lm( y~poly(x,3) )
fit4 <- lm( y~poly(x,9) )
library(splines)
fit5 <- lm( y~ns(x, 3) )
fit6 <- lm( y~ns(x, 9) )

fit7 <- lm( y ~ x + cos(x*pi) )

xx <- seq(0,11, length.out=250)
lines(xx, predict(fit1, data.frame(x=xx)), col='blue')
lines(xx, predict(fit2, data.frame(x=xx)), col='green')
lines(xx, predict(fit3, data.frame(x=xx)), col='red')
lines(xx, predict(fit4, data.frame(x=xx)), col='purple')
lines(xx, predict(fit5, data.frame(x=xx)), col='orange')
lines(xx, predict(fit6, data.frame(x=xx)), col='grey')
lines(xx, predict(fit7, data.frame(x=xx)), col='black')
```

Which of those models is the best?  arguments could be made for any of them (but I for one would not want to use the purple one for interpolation).

Answer (score 17):

Regarding the question 'can R help me find the best fitting model', there is probably a function to do this, assuming you can state the set of models to test, but this would be a good first approach for the set of n-1 degree polynomials:

```
polyfit <- function(i) x <- AIC(lm(y~poly(x,i)))
as.integer(optimize(polyfit,interval = c(1,length(x)-1))$minimum)
```

Notes

- The validity of this approach will depend on your objectives, the assumptions of `optimize()` and `AIC()` and if AIC is the criterion that you want to use,
- `polyfit()` may not have a single minimum. check this with something like:

  ```
  for (i in 2:length(x)-1) print(polyfit(i))
  ```
- I used the `as.integer()` function because it is not clear to me how I would interpret a non-integer polynomial.
- for testing an arbitrary set of mathematical equations, consider the ['Eureqa'](http://ccsl.mae.cornell.edu/eureqa) program reviewed by Andrew Gelman [here](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~cook/movabletype/archives/2009/12/equation_search.html)

**Update**

Also see the `stepAIC` function (in the MASS package) to automate model selection.

Comment: How can I interface Eurequa with R?

Comment: @adam.888 great question - I don't know the answer but you could post it separately. That last point was a bit of a digression.

Comment: Note: AIC is the _Akaike Information Criterion_, which rewards a close fit and penalises a larger number of parameters of a model, in a way that has been shown to be optimal in various senses. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akaike_information_criterion

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to find the best fit in R is to code the model as:

```
lm.1 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2) + I(x^3) + I(x^4) + ...)
```

After using step down AIC regression

```
lm.s <- step(lm.1)
```

Comment: Using `I(x^2)`, etc. doesn't give appropriately orthogonal polynomials for fitting.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if we want to fit a polynomial of degree 2, we can directly do it by solving a system of linear equations in the following way:

[image]

The following example shows how to fit a parabola y = ax^2 + bx + c using the above equations and compares it with `lm()` polynomial regression solution. Hope this will help in someone's understanding,

```
x <- c(32,64,96,118,126,144,152.5,158)  
y <- c(99.5,104.8,108.5,100,86,64,35.3,15)

x4 <- sum(x^4)
x3 <- sum(x^3)
x2 <- sum(x^2)
x1 <- sum(x)
yx1 <- sum(y*x)
yx2 <- sum(y*x^2)
y1 <- sum(y)

A <- matrix(c(x4, x3, x2,
              x3, x2, x1,
              x2, x1, length(x)), nrow=3, byrow=TRUE)
B <- c(yx2,
       yx1,
       y1)

coef <- solve(A, B)   # solve the linear system of equations, assuming A is not singular
coef1 <- lm(y ~ x + I(x^2))$coef  # solution with lm

coef
# [1] -0.01345808  2.01570523 42.51491582
rev(coef1)
#     I(x^2)       x         (Intercept) 
#     -0.01345808  2.01570523 42.51491582 

plot(x, y, xlim=c(min(x), max(x)), ylim=c(min(y), max(y)+10), pch=19)
xx <- seq(min(x), max(x), 0.01)
lines(xx, coef[1]*xx^2+coef[2]*xx+coef[3], col='red', lwd=3, lty=5)
lines(xx,  coef1[3]*xx^2+ coef1[2]*xx+ coef1[1], col='blue')
legend('topright', legend=c("solve", "lm"),
       col=c("red", "blue"), lty=c(5,1), lwd=c(3,1), cex=0.8,
       title="quadratic fit", text.font=4)
```

[image]