# How can I insert a polynomial fit into a function?

Tags: r, curve-fitting

```
8,27268
17,7308
29,5468
59,4136
149,3741
299,1438
599,297
749,113
750,44
```

These are my data and I would like to find the polynomial fit and put it in a function.

Comment: What order of polynomial? See [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822535/fitting-polynomial-model-to-data-in-r).

Answer (score 0):

If this is your sample data

```
dd<-data.frame(
    x = c(8, 17, 29, 59, 149, 299, 599, 749, 750), 
    y = c(27268, 7308, 5468, 4136, 3741, 1438, 297, 113, 44)
)
```

You can fit a polynomial with any order using the `poly()` function. Here I fit a 3rd order polynomial

```
fit <- lm(y~poly(x,3),dd)

# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 3), data = dd)
# 
# Coefficients:
# (Intercept)  poly(x, 3)1  poly(x, 3)2  poly(x, 3)3  
#        5535       -14073         8504        -6091
```

Now I can plot the results

```
plot(dd)
x <- seq(min(dd$x), max(dd$x), length.out=100)
lines(x, predict(fit, newdata=data.frame(x=x)))
```

[image]