# how do i square a variable in r studio?

Tags: r, regression

I want to run a regression with a squared variable. My original regression formula was:

```
lm(formula = ed ~ dist + female + bytest + tuition + 
             black + hispanic + incomehi + ownhome + 
             dadcoll + momcoll + cue80 + stwmfg80, 
             data = CollegeDistance)
```

I want to square the `dist` variable to add it into my formula. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Do you want to simply square it or square it within the formula?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3822535/fitting-polynomial-model-to-data-in-r