# Estimate cubic polynomial that maps set x to set y

Tags: c#, math, polynomial-math

I have a (sampled) set of uncalibrated values (x) coming from a device and a set of what they should be (y). I'm looking to find/estimate the cubic polynomial `y=ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d` that maps any `x` to `y`.

So I think what I need to do is Polynomial Regression first and then find its inverse, but I'm not so sure; and I wonder whether there is a better solution like least squares.

I would appreciate a nudge in the right direction and/or any links to a math library that would be of use.

Comment: I think I got muddled up and overcomplicated it; I think I just need Polynomial Regression with the given set of [x, y].

Comment: Similar [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/382186/fitting-polynomials-to-data) with a lot of references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like its just Polynomial Regression; I just need to feed in the raw (x) values and the expected values (y).

Code from [Rosetta Code](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Polynomial_regression), that uses [Math.Net Numerics](http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/)

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double.Factorization;
public static class PolyRegression
{
    public static double[] Polyfit(double[] x, double[] y, int degree)
    {
        // Vandermonde matrix
        var v = new DenseMatrix(x.Length, degree + 1);
        for (int i = 0; i < v.RowCount; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j <= degree; j++) v[i, j] = Math.Pow(x[i], j);
        var yv = new DenseVector(y).ToColumnMatrix();
        QR qr = v.QR();
        // Math.Net doesn't have an "economy" QR, so:
        // cut R short to square upper triangle, then recompute Q
        var r = qr.R.SubMatrix(0, degree + 1, 0, degree + 1);
        var q = v.Multiply(r.Inverse());
        var p = r.Inverse().Multiply(q.TransposeThisAndMultiply(yv));
        return p.Column(0).ToArray();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Langrange Interpolation?
It is about the polynomial approximation of a given function.

You can stop the approximation on a given degree of the polynomial (let's say the 3rd degree) on a proper range of the indipendent variable.

Refs:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_polynomial
- https://math.stackexchange.com/a/108623